# proof environment in beamer

Tags: beamer, theorems

I would need to move the symbol for the end of proof - a square a little bit up but ONLY on one slide, where the proof is quite long and the square has not seen very much.

Comment: Hi Laura! This one quite surely needs a MWE - in this case, a beamer document with only one or two slides showing your situation. The code should be compilable, i.e. start in `\documentclass` and end in `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

It's difficult to provide precise advise without a minimal working example; however, the following code reproduces the problem mentioned:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{proof}
\lipsum[4]
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
\lipsum[4]
\end{proof}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

the output shows that the qed symbol for the last `proof` environment almost disappears from the frame:

[image]

Adding a convenient `\vskip` just before `\end{proof}` solves the problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{proof}
\lipsum[4]
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
\lipsum[4]\vskip-1\baselineskip
\end{proof}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

One has to be careful about the length used for the `\vskip`; a value larger than `\baselineskip` will produce undesired results.

As a personal note, you should reconsider using frames containing too much text (sometimes it's unavoidable, but give it a second thought).